# Is the latest version of rstan 2.26.2 avaiable for Ubuntu 20.04 LT?

Tags: package-management, r

Is the latest version of rstan (2.26.2) available yet on Ubuntu 20.04 LT?  If not yet, is there an estimate of when it will be available?

Comment: I don't see a package of the name `rstan` but if you know the package name you can look up yourself and even if you can't get an actual date, you'll have enough detail to have a fair idea when it'll be (ie. where is it from, how well maintained has it been in the past is a good clue on what is likely into the future).  A search produced many results so given I don't know which package you'll mean specifically; you can look yourself.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/r-cran-rstan says 2.19.2, and 2.26.2 will *never* be available for 20.04

Comment: What is wrong with `R -e "install.packages('rstan')"` from [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstan/index.html) ?

Comment: NOrbert:  The current version available on CRAN is 2.19, as muru says.  The more recent version 2.26, has some functions not in 2.19.

Comment: > Muru:  2.26.2 will never be available for 20.04  Why not?  It is available for Windows 10?